# Break the try and go directly to the exception if condition is false

Tags: python

I have a complex code in python with condition inside try:

```
try:
   if condition is True: execute the code 
   else: go to exception and don't execute the code
except:
   execute the except statement
```

I want to exit the try statement if condition is met

Comment: What do you mean by exit try statment ?

Comment: the code inside try

Comment: You can throw an exception using the `raise` keyword. Like any other exception it will be caught and the code will execute the `except`.

Comment: Be more clear with your intention. With the current version of your question, it seems like there is no need for `try-except`. Simply an `if-else` would do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just manually raise an exception:

```py
try:
    if condition:
        your code
    else:
        raise Exception('Exception message')
except:
    # except code here
```